# Can I deploy an Azure Mobile Service .NET backend to an Azure Website

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-web-app-service

I guess the question is kind of double barreled, but can I deploy an azure mobile service .net backend to an azure website and if so how (can anyone point me to any resources regarding this or is it as simple as hitting the deploy button)?

Thanks

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is doable, although you will encounter issues trying to use the authentication features. These take a dependency on the URL being *.azure-mobile.net, as can be seen from the specified values in the [documentation](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-xamarin-ios-get-started-users/). Since you cannot assign this domain to a Web App, the features will not behave as expected.

Otherwise, the Mobile Services project is just another Web API, and Azure Web Apps (formerly "Web Sites") is a valid publish target.

It's worth calling out App Service Mobile Apps (as brought up by @beast), as this scenario falls naturally from it. Mobile Apps explicitly exposes the Web App that underlies Mobile Services and allows you to leverage all of the Web App features. You can read more about Mobile Apps [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/mobile/) and [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-value-prop-preview/), and there's some comparison content against Mobile Services [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-changes-existing-services/?clcid=0x409) and [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-value-prop-migration-from-mobile-services-preview/)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this personally, but adding your Azure website publisher settings and deploying should technically work.

Considering that the solution provided is a ASP.net MVC solution.